# How can I scroll up and down test with one composable(Column and LazyColumn) function in androidTest?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to test scroll up and down and the scrollBar moves and behaves correctly.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LazyScrollColumnTest {
    @get:Rule
    val rule = createComposeRule()

    private val focusableTag = "focusable"
    private val lazyScrollState = LazyListState(0)

    @Before
    fun before() {
        isDebugInspectorInfoEnabled = true
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        isDebugInspectorInfoEnabled = false
    }

    @Test
    fun scrollDown() {
        rule.setContent {
            LazyScrollColumn (
                state = lazyScrollState,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().testTag(focusableTag)
            ){
                items(30) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Item $it",
                        fontSize = 100.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        requestFocusAndScrollToTDown()
    }

    @Test
    fun scrollUp() {
        rule.setContent {
            LazyScrollColumn (
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ){
                items(30) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Item $it",
                        fontSize = 100.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        requestFocusAndScrollToTop()
    }

    private fun requestFocusAndScrollToTop() {
        requestFocus()
        scrollToTop()
    }

    private fun requestFocusAndScrollToTDown() {
        requestFocus()
        scrollToDown()
    }


    private fun requestFocus(tag: String = focusableTag) {
        rule.onNodeWithTag(tag).performSemanticsAction(SemanticsActions.RequestFocus)
    }

    private fun scrollToTop() {
        rule.waitForIdle()
        // Reset scroll to top since requesting focus will scroll it.
        runBlocking {
            lazyScrollState.scrollToItem(0)
        }
    }

    private fun scrollToDown() {
        rule.waitForIdle()
        // Reset scroll to top since requesting focus will scroll it.
        runBlocking {
            lazyScrollState.scrollToItem(30)
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://shorturl.at/muAD7) is my code and my Reference: [ScrollableFocusableInteractionTest](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/androidAndroidTest/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/ScrollableFocusableInteractionTest.kt;l=316?q=scrollable%20test&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:compose%2F)

Comment: Have you ever checked this document: [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing)
Because it teaches how you can test a composable.

Comment: @dev.basilinnia yes, sure. I read it but didn't help in my case. It just shows simple cases.